# Clojure: [Soft] Working from the Repl

Tags: clojure

### Context

Quoting the ClojureScript documentation:

> When working with ClojureScript, having a good workflow is essential. The first thing to know about workflow is that you should be working from the REPL as much as possible. In fact, if you are not spending most of your time in the REPL, you're doing it wrong.

Now, in most of my Clojure development -- I work in my editor -- and hot-reload my code in the REPL.

### Question:

(1) Does anyone have a good setup for coding *Clojure* in the repl rather than in an editor? What are the advantages?

(2) What is different a about Clojure vs ClojureScript that makes ClojureScript good for woking directly in the repl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Using the repl in your editor counts as the repl ;) if that's what you do then so you are already doing it right. if you have your edit and yoru repl not integrated then may I introduce you to [slime](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit) and [slimv](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2531).  EDIT: It sounds like you already have a handle on this one, so for other readers, especially for vim users, slimv really makes this process a lot more fun, it adds thing like 'jump to function deffinition' and lets you compile a form right from the buffer where you are editing it. **I am jumping up and down with enthusiasm over how much better life is with working slimv** (and slime on emacs)

2: clojurescript is different only in that the your repl is running wiht a browser. have you tried the the browser repl included with ClojureScript?

Comment: (1) I edit in vim. Then I hit ":make" which sends a command over tcp to the "lein repl" to reload all necessary files. (2) If by (cljs-repl), (js/alert "Hello World") -- then yes.

Comment: You should look at Vimclojure, which will let you get most of what slime/slimv do. https://bitbucket.org/kotarak/vimclojure